# Are geolocation services using other methods than pure IP address?

Tags: geolocation, ip-address, vpn

More than a question this may be general information . I am using a VPN service and located in the Middle East. I've found most (if not all but one)  IP geolocation webpages shows my location as New York which matches the VPN IP address. But the service whatismyipaddres_dot_com shows the correct IP address and my location in Kuwait. Clicking some links on the mentioned webpage it takes me to a page showing they use several services from which one is showing Kuwait and the other two New York. However,contary on the expected "majority vote", they pick the single one different which,  in fact,  is right. As you can see they do not mention the name, but I believe the provider is Maxmind (maxmind_dot_com).

Sorry, not allowed to post images!!

Does anyone knows what they may be using ( router MAC? Google account ?).I use VPN to access ESPN , etc , but if this method is used by all other geoloc services in the future ,it  will render the VPN unusable !

Answer (score 0):

The web site whatismyipaddress dot com is using a mixture of HTML5 geolocation and IP geolocation.

Most likely your MAC address are being used to geolocate the location using HTML5 than using IP address geolocation.

Source: http://www.geolocation.com